# Visit a polymorphic type, like a variant without knowing the exact subtypes

Tags: c++, polymorphism, type-erasure, dynamic-dispatch

There are times when knowing the actual subtype of a polymorphic object is beneficial - like ensuring no virtual calls happen in a loop where we invoke a virtual function repeatedly. Making `std::variant` extendable towards the end-users of a library is a huge pain, it's a lot nicer to have an interface instead.

Ideally, I could do something like this:

```cpp
struct base {
    virtual void foo() = 0;
};

struct derived : base {
    virtual void foo() override {}
};

// Sample
base* b = new derived{};
b->invoke_with_subtype([](auto* subtype) {
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(subtype), derived*>);
});
```

Of course, life isn't that ideal, I'd need to inject that function somehow. I was thinking some kind of CRTP trick, but I keep running into the same problem again and again, that I just can't erase that passed generic lambda function.

**TL;DR:** Is it possible to do dynamic dispatch on polymorphic types without a lot of boilerplate and knowing all the subtypes in advance?

Comment: Would you be happy if you couldn't use a generic lambda? E.g. `b->invoke_with_subtype([](derived& subtype) { /* ... */ });`?

Comment: @Justin I believe that would defeat the purpose. The fact that the lambda is generic is what introduces most of the complexity : *"I keep running into the same problem again and again, that I just can't erase that passed generic lambda function."*

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux But you definitely have to know `derived` inside the body of the lambda, otherwise you can't use it. I don't see the benefit of making the lambda a generic lambda.

Comment: @Justin I think the goal is to get the concrete type but only use the common `base` interface. Whether or not this is actually useful is debatable, but it doesn't matter. The question is not about the application. For example, another use case I can imagine is getting `sizeof(subtype)` in the functor.

Comment: @Justin I believe that multiple subtypes would be impossible in that case (also capturing would be affected I think). (Answering to first comment)

Comment: This question is a mind bender. It looks solvable, but every avenue seems to lead to a hard brick wall.

Comment: @PeterLenkefi I'm fairly sure that the desired usage is impossible. `base` has no way of knowing what type it could actually be, and thus no way to send that to the generic lambda. Effectively what you want is the ability to add ad-hoc virtual functions to the `base` class, without specifying which derived classes the implementation should apply to. This is not possible.

Comment: If the concern is repeatedly invoking a virtual function, consider manual vtables in a manner similar to [dyno](https://github.com/ldionne/dyno), then preload the vtable before doing the repeated invoking. You'll pay for the cost of a function call, but not for the cost of looking up the function through the vtable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

Solving the problem as described requires runtime/dynamic link time reification of template code.  This is a feature that C++ lacks.

Modest restrictions remove that need, but all have tradeoffs.  Most require a list of supported types somewhere, or a list of supported operations.

Fancy alternative object models permit splitting vtables from instances and "RLE"-ing types in buffers and similar, but that also doesn't do what you describe.

TL;DR remains "No" is the answer to your question, you cannot do that.

---

SO is best suited to concrete, practical problems.  In my experience if you have an actual practical use case, 9/10 there is an implicit restriction in your practical use case that makes your problem solvable.

Instead, you produce an abstract solition that would be sufficient to solve your real problem.  The issue is that your abstract solution isn't possible to solve.

Of course, 99/100 questions like this don't have an actual practical concrete problem they are solving.

If you have an actual practical concrete problem, I encourage you to post a question about it instead of this abstraction.  My hobby is finding SO posts whose sensible answer is "no" and providing insensible "yes" answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `derived* test = dynamic_cast<derived*>(object)` to test for a specific sub-type: if `object` really is `derived` then `test` will be a pointer to it but, if it's actually a `base` then `test` will be `nullptr`.

Comment: I think you misunderstand, I'd like to deduce the subtype and call the callback with it, just like `std::visit` does. The challenge is that I don't know the options (kinds of subtypes)

Comment: @Peter Lenkefi OK, then your **TL;DR** section probably invalidates my answer: you would need a whole stack of tests and callbacks.